# How to pass custom filter result to original component?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am trying to implement custom filtering on date field.
I created

```
<clr-datagrid (clrDgRefresh)="refresh($event)" [clrDgLoading]="loading">
...

  <clr-dg-column>
    Conflict
    <clr-dg-filter>
      <date-filter #conflict></date-filter>
    </clr-dg-filter>
  </clr-dg-column>


  <clr-dg-row *ngFor="let d of data">
    <clr-dg-cell>{{d.lastUpdated | date}}</clr-dg-cell>
  </clr-dg-row>

  <clr-dg-footer>
    {{pagination.firstItem + 1}} - {{pagination.lastItem + 1}} of {{total}} data
    <clr-dg-pagination #pagination [clrDgTotalItems]="total"></clr-dg-pagination>
  </clr-dg-footer>
</clr-datagrid>
```

A component which holds this is

```
  refresh(state: ClrDatagridStateInterface<User>) {
    this.loading = true;
    const filters: { [prop: string]: any[] } = {};
    if (state.filters) {
      for (const filter of state.filters) {
        const { property, value } = <{ property: string; value: string }>filter;
        filters[property] = [value];
      }
    }
    this.inventory
      .fetch(state.page.from, state.page.size)
      .then((result: FetchResult) => {
        this.user= result.user;
        this.total = result.length;
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
```

Date filter is another component having fields as

```
<form class="clr-form clr-form-compact" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
  <clr-input-container>
    <label>From</label>
    <input clrInput type="date" [(ngModel)]="model.from" name="search"/>
  </clr-input-container>
  <clr-input-container>
    <label>To</label>
    <input clrInput type="date" [(ngModel)]="model.to" name="search"/>
  </clr-input-container>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

And this is my component where I get from and to date inputs.

```
export class DateFilterComponent implements ClrDatagridFilterInterface < User> {

constructor(private filterContainer: ClrDatagridFilter) {
        filterContainer.setFilter(this);
  }

  changes: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>(false);

 model: search = {
    from: '',
    to: ''
 };

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log(this.model);
  }

  accepts(User: user) {
    return true;
  }

  isActive(): boolean {
    return true;
  }

}
```

I get dates in onFormSubmit method but I want to send it to original component which handles the fetching part but not sure how to do it. Also there are multiple fields 
where I would like custom filtering so there should ideally be single filtering method which has all the filtering data but couldn't find how to do it in clarity.

Comment: Cross column filtering is a planned addition in the backlog: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1632

Answer (score 0):

I only need to emit the event and rest is taken care by clarity so in submit form I do this and it calls refresh event.

this.changes.emit(new Select());